# How to configure Soap Webservices using Spring ws

Tags: spring

I am new to the Spring ws.For the following things i need some clarification

1.I want to know how to customise the bindings,operations,port names etc..that is generated automatially by Spring.

2.How to specify multiple bindings,port types if we have multiple operations so that all should be generated in same wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the dynamic WSDL properties using `DefaultWsdl11Definition` bean

```
@Bean
public DefaultWsdl11Definition orders() {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    definition.setPortTypeName("Orders");
    definition.setLocationUri("http://localhost:8080/ordersService/");
    definition.setSchema(new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("echo.xsd")));

    return definition;
}
```

Ref : http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/server.html

API Doc : http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/wsdl/wsdl11/DefaultWsdl11Definition.html